# Many-To-One relation results in DbUpdateException

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, one-to-many

I have the following problem:

I have a class `Foo` which has a list of `IBar`s. Since it's an interface and there can be many implementations the entity framework cannot save this property by itself to the database. To solve this I just created another list property of a different type (`BarDatabaseObject`), which is easily serializable. The idea is that the concrete implementation/instance of the `IBar` is just serialized into a single field on the DB while the only other field in this table is the `Id`.

However this doesn't work. I get an `UpdateException`:

```
System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.
---> System.Data.Entity.Core.UpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.
---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_dbo.BarDatabaseObject'.
Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.BarDatabaseObject'.
The duplicate key value is (a3450574-2d93-4c90-bcdf-88779d18068c).
```

I'm 100% positive that I don't have a duplicated key, since I only add one `IBar` object to the list and the database is empty before.

After some investigation I found out that the entity framework calls the property `BarsDatabaseObjects` multiple times. Since I always create a new list with new objects (but with the exact same values!) there, the entity framework doesn't realize that it's the same object when accessing the property the first time and assumes it must be a new `BarDatabaseObject` and therefore tries to also add it to the database.

How can I solve this problem? The scenario seems simple enough to me (and not even that "special").

Thanks for your help.

```
internal class Program
{
  private static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    var dbContext = ....;
    Foo foo = ...; //initialize it, with all properties
    dbContext.Foos.Add(foo); //exception occurs here!
    dbContext.SaveChanges();
  }
}

public class Foo
{
  public Guid Id { get; set; }

  //cannot be saved by entity framework, because it's an interface
  [NotMapped]
  public List<IBar> Bars { get; set; }

  public virtual List<BarDatabaseObject> BarsDatabaseObjects
  {
    get
    {
      return Bars.Select(c => new BarDatabaseObject
      {
        Id = c.Id,
        ImplementationsAsJson = JsonSerializer.Serialize(c)
      }).ToList();
    }
    set
    {
      Bars = value.Select(c => JsonSerializer.Deserialize<IBar>(c.ImplementationsAsJson))
                  .ToList();
    }
  }

  // many implementations of this interface exists
  public interface IBar
  {
    Guid Id { get; }
  }

  public class BarDatabaseObject
  {
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string ImplementationsAsJson { get; set; }

    public Guid? FooId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(FooId))]
    public virtual Foo Foo { get; set; }
  }
```

Comment: What about adding backing field for BarsDatabaseObjects?

Comment: What do you mean? And then only "initialize" it once and then keep the same value?

Comment: Yes, but not exactly. Initialize and keep same object, change it when you set Bars.